# javascript: image won't change

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty sure logic is fine, but for some other reason, when I click on the image, it doesn't change. All of the images are in the same directory, and I could load lightOn.png image, but can not change it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            function changeImage() {
                if (document.getElementById("myimg").src == "lightOn.png") {
                    document.getElementById("myimg").src = "lightOff.png";
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("myimg").src = "lightOn.png";
                }
            }
        </script>
        <img id="myimg" onclick="changeImage()" src="lightOn.png">
        <p>Turn on/off the light</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Only issue I can see here is the image path

Comment: Your code should work. Please review that the file exists.

I would load images before in order to avoid a blank image while switching from "lightOn.png" to "lightOff.png". Even better I would use a CSS Sprite and with JS only change the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem that seems to exist is that the img src is not correct, make sure path to your image is correct. I changed the path and it works http://jsfiddle.net/Y4yCb/

```
<body>
        <script>
            function changeImage() {
                if (document.getElementById("myimg").src == "http://www.freeimageslive.com/galleries/light/pics/light00002g.jpg") {
                    document.getElementById("myimg").src = "http://solar.calfinder.com/assets/blog/images/energy-light-off.jpg";
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("myimg").src = "http://www.freeimageslive.com/galleries/light/pics/light00002g.jpg";
                }
            }
        </script>
        <img id="myimg" onclick="changeImage()" src="http://www.freeimageslive.com/galleries/light/pics/light00002g.jpg">
        <p>Turn on/off the light</p>
    </body>
```

Comment: Yes path was the problem, thanks...